# $data = array() vs unset($array)

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, unset

this is my first question.

I am doing some optimizations on a php script, improving its speed of execution...

Between :

```
$datas = array();
$datas['file_import'] = $file_name_reporting;
```

And :

```
unset($datas);
$datas['file_import'] = $file_name_reporting;
```

Can someone tell me which one is faster ?

Thank you

Comment: »Premature optimization is the root of all evil« I doubt this line of code is the bottleneck of your code …

Answer (score 3):

Your second example causes warning, because `$datas` is right now `null` and you are treating it as an array, so you have to declare it as an empty array before.

So just follow your first example - assign an empty array and then put into it some data.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to say that $datas has a lot of element inside it.
Does it change the answer or not ?

Comment: Nope, it does not changes my answer. Just assign an empty array to `$datas` and forget about `unset` - it's useless here.

Answer (score 1):

array() will create an array whereas unset() will destroy a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think first method is just a overwriting but second one includes deleting, checking existence, triggering warning and creating new array

Answer (score 1):

It's ridiculous to claim that either form is "faster" than the other. Both versions will execute so fast that you would need to run them millions of times inside a loop to perhaps notice a difference. Do you actually do that inside your script? If not, forget about "optimization" here (actually, it would be a good idea to forget about *all* optimization "by eye", as any experienced developer can tell you).

On top of that, the two versions actually *do different things*, in that `unset` will remove the name `$datas` from the sumbol table (and give you a notice in the next line when you attempt to add a value to an array).

Just use what feels right, and look inside heavy loops to find something to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, a new Array will be constructed. Unsetting a variable in php, will set it's value to null, only to call the array constructor on the next line. Although I agree with knittl, my suggestion would be:

```
$datas = array('file_import' => $file_name_reporting);
```

By creating a new array, you automatically 'unset' the variable, and by passing values to the array constructor, you can fill your array with whatever values you want while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the first code will work faster because you do only two operations: explicitly create an array and add a portion of data. The second example will cause a warning because you destroy a variable and then try to use it again.

Additionally `unset` will not release used memory, it will only release a pointer on variable. Memory will be released when gc will be runned. To release a memory, use `$datas = null;` instead.